# useEffect updating because redux state changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

In my app I have multiple useEffect hooks and a redux global state. Now depending on the change of the redux state the useEffect hook should run when the variable changes, which it does. My dispatch and useEffect hooks look like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const fetchOrder = useCallback((uuid: string) => dispatch(thunkFetchOrder(uuid)), [dispatch]);
const fetchDebtor = useCallback((uuid: string | undefined) => dispatch(thunkFetchDebtor(uuid)), [dispatch]);
const fetchOrderPayments = useCallback((uuid: string) => dispatch(thunkFetchOrderPayments(uuid)), [dispatch]);
    
const orderInState: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.order);
const debtorInState: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.debtor);

useEffect(() => { fetchOrder(props.route.params.orderUuid); }, []);
useEffect(() => { setOrder(orderInState); }, [orderInState.order.uuid]);
useEffect(() => { setDebtor(debtorInState.debtor); console.log('update') }, [debtorInState.debtor.id]);
useEffect(() => { setOrderPayments(orderInState.payments); }, [orderInState.payments]);
```

For example the useEffect hook with setOrder(orderInState) should only run when orderInState.order.uuid changes. However, it runs multiple times. The reducer for the order API call looks like this:

```
 const initialState: OrderState = {
    order: {
        uuid: ''
    },
    payments: []
}

export function orderReducer(
    state = initialState,
    action: OrderActionTypes
): OrderState{
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_ORDER_REQUEST:
            if (state.order.uuid!== action.uuid) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    order: {}
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state
                }
            }
        case FETCH_ORDER:
            return {
                ...state,
                order: action.payload
            }

        case FETCH_ORDER_PAYMENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                payments: action.payload
            }
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My redux global state looks like this:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    error: errorReducer,
    debtor: debtorReducer,
    debtors: debtorsReducer,
    order: orderReducer,
    orders: ordersReducer,
    payments: paymentsReducer,
    roles: rolesReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
    credentials: credentialsReducer
})
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use the elimination method. Disable all reducer except orders, and uncomment them one by one till you find out where is the state update effects.

Comment: The problem is that all the useEffect hooks execute multiple times not just the orders one. My bad, I guess I should have stated that more clearly.

Comment: For the specific orderReducer, check where you update order.uuid. I can see other functions effected by this.

Comment: I realized that I had posted the wrong reducer. Could you explain how this affects other functions?

Comment: @stefan0905 You can check if your component is remounted, that could trigger the effect again. Then check redux devtools to see what action is changing the id.